# PHPUnit and WebDriver - How to get the current URL?

Tags: selenium, phpunit

Scenario:
 I open www.google.com, input some keywords and click the search button.
 now i get to the result page. I want to get the current url of this result page, including the query parameters.

I found a method `getBrowserUrl()` here [phpunit-selenium on github](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php). Line 410

But this method returned the value which I set in the `setUp` function.

```
public function setUp(){
$this->setBrowser(testConfig::$browserName);
$this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.google.com/');
}

public function testGoogleSearch(){
$this->url('');
//input some keywords
.......
//click search button
.......
//want to get the url of result page
$resultUrl= $this->getBrowserUrl();
echo $resultUrl;
}
```

I got a string 'http://www.google.com/' instead of the whole url of result page.
Please help me,thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can call `getLocation()` on the driver, [as seen in source](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php#L1115).

Comment: @rutter It's a selenium RC method .I can't use it for Selenium2 Webdriver. However,I tried it,there's an error"BadMethodCallException: The command 'getLocation' is not existent or not supported yet".Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is:

```
$currentURL = $this->url();
```

I also asked this question [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/291)

Thanks to [@jaruzafa](https://github.com/jaruzafa)

Answer (score 4):

From the source code, I'd say it's getCurrentURL()

https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/blob/787e71db74e42cdf13a41d500f75ea43da84bc75/lib/WebDriver.php#L43

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

`$url=$this->getLocation();`

Comment: getLocation() returns coordinates (WebDriverPoint): "Get the location of element relative to the top-left corner of the page." (https://php-webdriver.github.io/php-webdriver/latest/Facebook/WebDriver/WebDriverElement.html#method_getLocation)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'll get the current URL

```php
$resultUrl = $this->getSession()->getDriver()->getCurrentUrl();
echo $resultUrl;
```

or

```php
$resultUrl = $this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl();
echo $resultUrl;
```

Both are from Behat - Mink

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an older version of PHPUnit Selenium this might be helpful:

```
$url = $this->getEval('window.location.href;');
$this->assertEquals('EXPECTEDURL', $url);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
$urlAry = $driver->executeScript('return window.location',array());
$currentURL = $urlAry['href'];
```